# How to solve Node JS modules conflict in TFS extension (FileSystem)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tfs, azure-devops

I'm developing an extension for TFS.
This extension is based on : "**build-results-enhancer**"

From: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer

I would like to read the content of a file that I'm getting from the "**DT_Client**" in the "tab.ts" file

```
                 var taskClient = DT_Client.getClient();
                 taskClient.getPlanAttachments(vsoContext.project.id, "build", build.orchestrationPlan.planId, "myattachment").then((taskAttachments) => {

                     $.each(taskAttachments, (index, taskAttachment) => {

                         var element3 = $("<div />");
                         element3.text(JSON.stringify("taskAttachment._links.self" + taskAttachment._links.self, null, 2));
                         this._element.append(element3);


                        if (taskAttachment._links && taskAttachment._links.self && taskAttachment._links.self.href) {
                            var link = taskAttachment._links.self.href;
                            var attachmentName = taskAttachment.name;

                            var fileData = fs.readFileSync(link, 'utf8');

                                var element44 = $("<div />");
                                element44.text(JSON.stringify(fileData, null, 2));
                                this._element.append(element44);
```

I'm getting the attachment, but the problem beggin when I want to use the "fs" module. I imported the "filesystem" module. and the TS to JS process goes without any problem and also the extension compilation .

But when I run it on TFS I get this exception:

```
Error: Script error for: FileSystem
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror  basejs:53:860
c http://localhost:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/Dev14.M102/_scripts/TFS/min/basejs:53:860
ni/s.onScriptError http://localhost:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/Dev14.M102/_scripts/TFS/min/basejs:53:11964
```

What am I doing wrong? Does the "**FileSystem**" module can't "live" with the "**vss-web-extension-sdk**" module?

Can I use a workaround instead of the fs?

Comment: Could you please check the description of your error at http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror . Could you provide more information you could find from the console log of your browser (usually you can reach that with "Inspect Element" or F12 key afaik).

Comment: Its from the Inspect Element window